# Save virtual fields to a layer definition file

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to save virtual fields (with their expression) a layer definition file without them becoming static fields?

I have about a dozen virtual fields in many tables with complex expressions, which need to be replicated in about another 20+ projects.  I would really like to find a way that I can replicate the virtual fields into the other projects without needing to recreate and copy/paste the expressions for every single virtual field.

Answer (score 4):

**Virtual fields are part of the layer's style. Styles can be transferred from one layer to another.**

- Within the same QGIS project, you can copy/paste style from one layer to another. Right click on the layer name in the Layer panel > Styles > Copy/Paste style > Fields.

[image]

- To transfer a style from one project to another, save the layer's style as a QGIS QML style file. Layer properties > symbology > style > save/load style.

[image]

**Note**: In QGIS 3, you can transfer individual parts of the style. QGIS 2.18 only allows you to transfer the entire style.

Comment: Thanks! That's an ideal solution - unfortunately for these projects we're still using 2.18

Comment: For multiple projects in QGIS 2.18, probably the best method is to save the style (with virtual fields) as the default style for that layer. Whenever you add that layer to a new project, it will automatically load with that style.

Comment: Or you can store the expression in a string field in the attribute table, and use the `eval()` function in the Field Calculator. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311279/how-to-re-use-an-expression-stored-as-a-string-in-qgis-field-calculator/311280#311280

Comment: @csk If i make changes to the layer with the default style, for ex add new fields, does the styöe update automatically or do I need to resave it ?